# Avoiding nested Ifs when working with multiple Options and Eithers

Tags: scala

When I am coding with options I find the fold method very useful. Instead of writing if defined statements I can do

```
opt.fold(<not_defined>){ defined => }
```

this is good. but what to do if we are working with multiple options. or multiple eithers. Now I have to resort to writing code like

```
if (x.isDefined && y.isRight) {
  val z = getSomething(x.get)
  if (z.isDefined) {
    ....
```

Depending on the number of things involved, this code becomes very nested.

is there a functional trick to make this code a little un-nested and concise.... like the fold operation above?

Comment: Could you give me the type of the data you'd like to work with? Without that information, I'd guess you want http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html or https://github.com/atnos-org/eff-cats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried for comprehension? Assuming you don't want to treat individual errors or empty optionals:

```
import scala.util._

val opt1 = Some("opt1")
val either2: Either[Error, String] = Right("either2")
val try3: Try[String] = Success("try3")

for {
  v1 <- opt1
  v2 <- either2.right.toOption
  v3 <- try3.toOption
} yield {
  println(s"$v1 $v2 $v3")
}
```

Note that `Either` is not right biased, so you need to call the `.right` method on the for comprehension (I think cats or scalaz have a right biased Either). Also, we are converting the `Either` and the `Try` to optionals, discarding errors

Answer (score 1):

Cases when `.isDefined` is followed by `.get` call can be refactored using custom extractors for pattern matching:

```
def getSomething(s: String): Option[String] = if (s.isEmpty) None else Some(s.toUpperCase)

object MyExtractor {
  def unapply(t: (Option[String], Either[Int, String])): Option[String] =
    t match {
      case (Some(x), Right(y)) => getSomething(x)
      case _ => None
    }
}

val x: Option[String] = Some("hello world")
val y: Either[Int, String] = Right("ok")

(x, y) match {
  case MyExtractor(z) => z // let's do something with z
  case _ => "world"
}
// HELLO WORLD
```

We managed to get rid of all `.isDefined`, `.get` and even `.right` calls by replacing them by explicit pattern matching thanks to our custom extractor `MyExtractor`.